# Remove the digit(s), the comma and the space at the left part of the line

Tags: replace, find, notepad++, digits

Sample data:

```
(17, ' Antonio Moreno Taquería (Restaurant) - 'Page 2' <br> ('4 februari 2024'),

(1, ' Cactus Comidas para llevar (Pizza) - 'Page 45' <br> ('7 april 2023'),

(58679, ' Drachenblut Delikatessen  Sven Ottlieb (Bar) - 'Page 22' <br> ('24 februari 1998'),

(19786453679, ' Furia Bacalhau e Frutos do Mar (Brasserie) - 'Page 21' <br> ('31 december 2001'),

(9871236, ' Hungry Coyote Import Store (Bar) - 'Page 87' <br> ('19 march 1988'),

(236, ' Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti    Giovanni Rovelli (Restaurant) - 'Page 256' <br> ('12 june 1984'),
```

I want to remove the digit(s), the comma and the space at the left part of the line but only 1 time per line.

Desired Result:

```
(' Antonio Moreno Taquería (Restaurant) - 'Page 2' <br> ('4 februari 2024'),

(' Cactus Comidas para llevar (Pizza) - 'Page 45' <br> ('7 april 2023'),

(' Drachenblut Delikatessen Sven Ottlieb (Bar) - 'Page 22' <br> ('24 februari 1998'),

(' Furia Bacalhau e Frutos do Mar (Brasserie) - 'Page 21' <br> ('31 december 2001'),

(' Hungry Coyote Import Store (Bar) - 'Page 87' <br> ('19 march 1988'),

(' Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti Giovanni Rovelli (Restaurant) - 'Page 256' <br> ('12 june 1984'),
```

I tried all kind of variations like `^.*(?=')` but Regex is absolutely not my field of expertise and it's all 'trial and error' what I'm doing. Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\(\d+,\h*`
- Replace with: `\(`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\(          # open parenthesis
\d+         # 1 or more digits
,           # a comma
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

Comment: unbelievable, what a quick answer and better, it worked perfectly. Thanks Toto. I really appreciate this.